# The display: "standalone" PWA does not remove address bar

Tags: manifest, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I made a PWA app, with `"display": "standalone"` in the manifest. My understanding is that my app should launch locally without the address bar. However, there is an address bar.

What am I doing wrong? I am running Chrome 70. The problem happens on OSX and Linux. I did not check Windows. My app is hosted at https://www.themendapp.com.

Please advise.

Comment: Desktop PWA support is still [early stage](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/desktop) and may not be fully implemented everywhere.

Comment: Your app works without address bar if I INSTALL your app (MacOS & Chrome 71), then clck on the icon here (chrome://apps/). I do not have an iOS device to test with. Did you get an install prompt there while in Chrome?

Comment: For me, it installs fine - From Chrome DevTools. I did not hookup the callback. Hence, it won't prompt by itself [with the latest Chrome]. Only, I do see the full address bar. ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

PWA app shows the address bar when you try to navigate the pages outside of `scope`. Otherwise it will hide the address bar and show the page in standalone mode.

For example if you have set your scope in manifest.json file as `scope: "/my-pwa/"` then all the page url should have prefix like this: `/my-pwa/page.html`.

Comment: than you so much for this. was tearing my hair out why the address bar was showing.